# SQL Connection(C#)-Executenonquery requires an open and available connections.connection current state is closed

Tags: c#

I am getting this error randomly in the production server. When I am executing the solution in my visual studio, not getting this error. I am capturing all exceptions in a log file. There I am getting this error. And also I have opened a connection before executenonquery. I have written the executenonquery inside using a statement of SQL connection.

```
try
{   
    try
    {
        Globale.OpenConnection();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["SubsRateCode"].ToString()))
            {
                continue;
            }
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_EstSubsRateDetail", conn, tn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EstSubsRateID", Globale.ConvertObjectToInteger(dr["EstSubsRateID"]));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EstimationID", oclsEstimationEntity.EstimationID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EstCode", oclsEstimationEntity.EstCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductDetailID", oclsEstimationEntity.ProductDetailID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnqID", oclsEstimationEntity.EnqID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnqCode", oclsEstimationEntity.EnqCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", dr["Category"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrdGroup", dr["PrdGroup"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrdType", dr["PrdType"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubsRateCode", dr["SubsRateCode"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdhesiveType", dr["AdhesiveType"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LinerType", dr["LinerType"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupCode", dr["SupCode"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubItemCode", dr["SubItemCode"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MasterPrice", Globale.ConvertObjectToDecimal(dr["MasterPrice"]));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MstSelect", Globale.ConvertObjectToInteger(dr["MstSelect"]));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WaccPrice", Globale.ConvertObjectToDecimal(dr["WaccPrice"]));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WcSelect", Globale.ConvertObjectToInteger(dr["WcSelect"]));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ManualPrice", Globale.ConvertObjectToDecimal(dr["ManualPrice"]));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MnpSelect", Globale.ConvertObjectToInteger(dr["MnpSelect"]));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MetersRoll", Globale.ConvertObjectToDecimal(dr["MetersRoll"]));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Width", Globale.ConvertObjectToDecimal(dr["Width"]));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubRemark", dr["SubRemark"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteRefrence", oclsEstimationEntity.Site_Refrence);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", Mode.ToString());
            lock (Globale.conn)
            {
                var connectionString = Globale.GetConnectionString();
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
                }
            }
            result = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        var st = new StackTrace(exception, true);
        // Get the top stack frame
        var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
        // Get the line number from the stack frame
        var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
        ErrorLog("c:/inetpub/wwwroot/BC_EEA1/error/error.txt", "EstDAL "+ System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, exception.Message, line, Globale.GetConnectionString(), oclsEstimationEntity.EstCode.ToString());
    }
}
finally
{
    if (cmd != null)
    {
        cmd = null;
    }
    Globale.CloseConnection();
}
```

Comment: The error message is very clear, your connection has been closed. Test your connection status prior to execute any request and if it has been closed reopen it.

Comment: I have opened connection before executenonquery.

Comment: You need to share the relevant code.

Comment: Better post your code if you want to get help.

Comment: `cmd.Connection = connection;` prior to `result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;`

Comment: You have opened *A* connection, but not the connection that the command is using. Also, you might want to reconsider sending each row to the database individually. Working with SQL Server means you can use table valued parameters - so you can send entire data tables to the database in one round-trip.